Date issues when switching from Postgres to SQL server as an extract in Tableau workbook
When I used PostgreSQL as a data source, I noticed a discrepancy in date handling compared to using SQL Server as a data source. Specifically, in Tableau, when I applied an extract filter, the start date is offset by one day earlier when using PostgreSQL compared to SQL Server. This discrepancy triggers a warning in Tableau and leads to inconsistent results in the Tableau workbook. Both server times are the same and both database's times are synced. Is anyone faced with the same issue?
Tableau Warning: The extract has a different time zone from the underlying server. Calculations using TODAY() and NOW() and relevant date filters will give different results.
Sql server datatype is datetime. Postgres datatype is timestamp without time zone.
I also cast the output to text but the issue not changed.

Can't say, but if you are using timezone-unaware data types in the database, the problem is probably in Tableau.

Please read [mre]: there is insufficient information in the post to recreate the problem. At the very least include example times, actual queries, and the returned results. Generic descriptions are seldom adequate. In PostgreSQL, values of type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, will be treated as being in the current session's time zone, which can be set using SET TIME ZONE. I don't recall SQL Server's behavior (it's been many years since I've used SQL Server).

The result of the Postgres and SQL Server Queries are the same in the database level. So when I used the result of query as a datasource in Tableau with the filter. The difference in the date appears. So, I don't think adding the Query can be helpful.

Timezone handing in Tableau is even more broken than timezone handling in SQL Server.  Use the "Init SQL" tab of Tableau's connection dialog to add set timezone='US/Eastern' or whatever timezone is appropriate for your data to apply a brute-force "fix".
